# Error in SearchBar while trying to write some thing using swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, uisearchbar

I'am trying to make a search bar in my table view but I have an error while trying to write any thing in the search bar , The error is (Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell1 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard') , I,am making a class to my cell and use it identifier as (cell1) but still the same error , can any one help me to solve this problem using Swift 3 .

[image: Cell ID][image: Cell Class]

This is My Code :

```
 import UIKit

  class ProgrTable: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate , UISearchBarDelegate  {

  @IBOutlet weak var ProgTable: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var searchActive : Bool = false
var filtered:[String] = []
var ProgArray = [UIImage]()
var ProgTitle = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.delegate = self
    ProgTable.dataSource = self
    ProgTable.delegate = self

    ProgArray = [UIImage(named :"1")!,UIImage(named :"1")!,UIImage(named :"1")!,UIImage(named :"1")!,UIImage(named :"1")!,UIImage(named :"1")!,UIImage(named :"1")!,UIImage(named :"1")!]

    ProgTitle = ["ssss ","kkkkkkk","vvvvvvv","yyyyyy","uuuuuu","eeeee","rrrrr","hhhhh","ggggg","fffff","dddd"]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = ProgTitle.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
        let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.ProgTable.reloadData()
}


 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if(searchActive) {
        return filtered.count
    }
    return ProgArray.count;
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1" , for: indexPath ) as! ProgrCell

    if(searchActive){
        cell.progLable.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.progLable.text = ProgTitle[indexPath.row]
         cell.progImage.image = ProgArray[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
 }


 }
```

This is My cell code :

```
import UIKit
```

class ProgrCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var progLable: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progImage: UIImageView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: set a cell identifier in IB as "cell1"

Comment: Not related but in `cellForRowAt` set `cell.progImage.image` to `UIImage()` when `searchActive` is `true`.

Comment: Please check the question after updating .

Comment: how odd - it all looks OK.  Have you checked that your filtered array holds the data you expect?

Answer (score 0):

In StoryBoard, select the cell, and make sure that the identifier is `cell1`, and that the class has been set to 'ProgrCell'

Comment: I'am sure that I'am doing all that but still the same error.

Comment: Could you add the code for `ProgrCell`, and - just to be absolutely sure :-) could you check that you have set the TableViewCell Style = Custom, and the Identifier = cell1 - with no quotes, commas or capitals?

Comment: Please check my question now .